# Display ajax content direclty from JSP

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, web, struts2

Is good practice to call jsp view with jquery tags? or there's another (And better) way to do this action this is my example

```
    <s:url id="log" value="login.jsp"/>
   <div id="signin" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
       <sj:div href="%{log}"></sj:div>
   </div>
   <a href="#signin" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal">
       Log in &nbsp; <i class="icon-chevron-right icon-white"></i>
   </a>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?